# Type of Memory Addressing in 8086

Tags: memory-address, x86-16

I am having a problem as to what [type of memory addressing](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Ecelio/mc404s2-03/addr_modes/intel_addr.html) would this assembly code be from:

- Immediate Addressing
- Direct Addressing
- Indrect Addressing
- Register Addressing
- Register Indirect
- Displacement
- Relative
- Base Register
- Indexed
- Stack
- Base Indexed plus Displacement

> mov dx, offset msg
>
> msg db "hello$"

where *msg* is a variable.

Comment: `mov dx, offset msg` is MOV r16, imm16 .It is move of a 16-bit immediate value to a 16 bit register. This doesn't actually address memory (although some 8086 documentation refer to this as immediate addressing). It simply moves the 16-bit offset(value) of the label `msg` into _DX_

Comment: It doesn't really matter from a programming perspective what it is called, as long as it does what you want. What is your programming question?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you! I placed this on direct as I was assuming that it was a direct type of addressing

Comment: @RaymondChen It's not about programming, I am only wondering as to what type of addressing the _mov dx, offset msg_ is.

Comment: Direct addressing would have been something like `mov dl, [msg]` . The byte stored at memory address at label `msg` is moved into 8-bit register _DL_. That would have the same effect of moving the letter `h` into _DL_.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is by its own admission not a programming question. Maybe it's a computer architecture question?

Comment: @RaymondChen what I meant about "it's not about programming" in my earlier statement is that, I want to properly optimize my program, and to do so, I believe that I must know on what type of addressing is the statement on top. As each type of addressing has its own upsides and downsides.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Got it. Thank you very much! I have properly reconfigured my assembly application with this.

Comment: Please phrase the question in terms of your actual programming problem. E.g. "What is the most efficient way to do X?" (Note also that the instruction in question doesn't use any addressing modes at all.)